# How does print() function work?

Tags: python, pretty-print

Say I have an Element class

```
class Element(object):
    def __init__(self,key,val):
        self.key = key
        self.val = val

    def __str__(self):
        return '(' + str(self.key) + ',' + str(self.val) + ')'
```

Now when I try to print an array that contains objects of the Element class

```
arr = [Element(10,20),Element(20,30)]
print(arr)
```

, the output is -

```
[<maxheap.Element object at 0x01C1FCB0>, <maxheap.Element object at 0x01C270B0>]
```

Which function is printing `<maxheap.Element object at 0x01C1FCB0>`? Why isn't the `__str__(self)` method called as in `print(Element(10,20))`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between \_\_str\_\_ and \_\_repr\_\_ in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Try using indexes instead of printing the list at once, like this:
    
    **`print(arr[0])`

    `print(arr[1])`**
Instead Of:
 
    **`print(arr)`**
**EDIT:**
Using `__repr__` works in this case.

Comment: But why? Using __repr(self)__ solves the issue meaning that print() calls repr(). I don't understand the use of __str(self)__ then.

Comment: @Kakaji Than please read the documentation. It's very clear/detailed there and on this network a real FAQ

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
def __repr__(self):
```

instead of

```
def __str__(self):
```